# Highcharts chart with Error bars from CSV

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create bar charts with Highcharts using data from a CSV exported from Excel. The examples I have seen of the data module seem to work fine, but how could I add error bar series and other information (such as a point special note or color, for example)?

I set up a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jmunger/z3oeu2aa/1/

The first chart uses simple CSV data.

The second chart has more complex CSV data, with columns for the Error bar's low and high, and columns for a specific datapoint note.

```html
<pre id="csv2" style="display: none">Year, Grade 1, Grade 1 Low, Grade 1 High, Grade 1 Note, Grade 2, Grade 2 Low, Grade 2 High,Grade 2 Note, Grade 3, Grade 3 Low, Grade 3 High, Grade 3 Note
2010-2011,1,0,2,999,2,1,4,,5,4,6,999
2012-2013,1,0,2,999,2,1,4,,5,4,6,999
2014-2015,1,0,2,999,2,1,4,,5,4,6,999</pre>
```

Obviously the second chart doesn't work at this time, since all columns create a regular series.

Is there a way to use the data module to handle such a CSV - at least partially?

The structure of the CSV file can be changed if necessary.

Comment: I think the best idea would be writing your own simple csv parser, you may also try playing with seriesMapping - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.seriesMapping

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with data module, I created an example with workaround using `data.seriesMapping`

```js
Highcharts.setOptions({
  chart: {
   events: {
     load () {
       this.series.forEach((s) => {
         // Workaround for data module problem
          if (s.name === 'Year') {
           s.update({data: [], visible: false, showInLegend: false})
          }
        })
      }
    },
    type: 'column',
    backgroundColor: '#F0F0F8',
    shadow: true
  }
})

$('#container1').highcharts({
  data: {
    csv: document.getElementById('csv2').innerHTML,
  seriesMapping: [
     { x: 0, y: 1, name: 1 },
      { x: 0, y: 5, name: 5 },
      { x: 0, y: 5, name: 5 },
      { x: 0, y: 9, name: 9 },
      { name: 0 }, { name: 0 }, { name: 0 }, { name: 0 }, { name: 0 } // Workaround for data module problem
    ]
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Complex CSV data'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<div id="container1"></div>

<pre id="csv2" style="display: none">Year, Grade 1, Grade 1 Low, Grade 1 High, Grade 1 Note, Grade 2, Grade 2 Low, Grade 2 High,Grade 2 Note, Grade 3, Grade 3 Low, Grade 3 High, Grade 3 Note
2010-2011,1,0,2,999,2,1,4,0,5,4,6,999
2012-2013,1,0,2,999,2,1,4,0,5,4,6,999
2014-2015,1,0,2,999,2,1,4,0,5,4,6,999</pre>
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/p8hbwzx0/